# Is there any way to fetch Hystrix Stream using java SSE clients

Tags: jersey, hystrix, turbine, event-stream, resiliency

Is there any way I can fetch Hystrix streams (which produces metrices), since it is a server side event stream, thus it is not possible to fetch it using normal http client.

I was trying to using Jersey based SSE, however it is not able to do so.

Whenever, hystrix makes a call it produces some metrics data which can be accessed through a servlet (sample url for which is like: ::/hystrix.stream).

I want to capture response of this stream on a particular time.

Any way to do this?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch any SSE events with jersey client. Here is a example that read from a SSE events as source and [broadcast](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.23.1/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/media/sse/SseBroadcaster.html) it to any clients that call *consumeEvent* resource method:

```
@Path("ssetest")
@Singleton
public class SSETest {
private static final SseBroadcaster sseBroadcaster = new SseBroadcaster();

private static OutboundEvent convert(InboundEvent in){
    OutboundEvent.Builder eventBuilder = new OutboundEvent.Builder();
    OutboundEvent out = eventBuilder.comment(in.getComment())
            .data(in.readData())
            .id(in.getId())
            .name(in.getName())
            .build();
    return out;
}

static {
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().register(SseFeature.class).build();
    WebTarget target = client.target("http://path/to/the/any/sse/event/producer/such/as/hystrix");
    EventSource eventSource = EventSource.target(target).build();
    EventListener listener = new EventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(InboundEvent inboundEvent) {
            sseBroadcaster.broadcast(convert(inboundEvent));
        }
    };
    eventSource.register(listener, "event");
    eventSource.open();
}

@GET
@Path("consumeEvent")
@Produces(SseFeature.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
public EventOutput consumeEvent(){
    EventOutput output = new EventOutput();
    sseBroadcaster.add(output);
    return output;
}
```

}

The static part make a call to SSE event producer and it gets events with EventListener. Please note that [EventSource](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.23.1/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/media/sse/EventSource.html) only registered this listener to the SSE events with "*event*" name. You must register it with the name of  hystrix event name.
Each time a client call *consumeEvent* resource method, it will receive the *hystrix* events.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to do the same, but it falls as we do not know the exact name.